# How can i customize the WIX pricing plans

Tags: velo

I have to make some changes to an existing Wix website, but I'm using the platform for the first time and don't know much about the options it has.
I have a question about the **pricing plans** and if it is possible to customize them more than the provided options.

Let me briefly explain what I have done so far:

- followed a tutorial and already added the pricing plans - without writing code just through the interface
- changed the settings and added the content I want from the dashboard
- also added the pricing page and the section and everything seems to work as it should

My problem is that as a requirement to these plans I need to have additional things like a dropdown with different currencies, a switch button  Pay monthly /
Pay annually and others. I can't find anywhere how I can add them to the pre-made section we're using and I'm starting to think there's no option to do that.

*I would be grateful if someone could tell me if it is even possible to add such additional options the way I have currently created the plans and if it is possible any guidance on how it can be done or useful resources to read.*